# ngx-translate - Change displayed value in language select dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

This seems like a relatively simple thing to do but I cannot seem to find any examples (Stackblitz, blogs, ngx-translate docs, etc.) of anyone doing it and cannot work it out myself.

I want to change the displayed value of my dropdown from "en", "es", "fr" to "English", "Espanol", "Francais". Changing the value in addLangs() seems to change the value in the dropdown but of course it cannot find en.json, etc.

component.html

```
<select class="form-control" selLang (change)="translateLanguageTo(selLang.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" [value]="language" [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
        {{ language }}
    </option>
</select>
```

app.component.ts

```
this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'es', 'fr']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed yourself, `ngx-translate` only cares about the language codes and not their names. You can work around this though.

Create a constant which contains all supported languages (language code + language name).

```
// supported-languages.ts
export const SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = [
  { code: 'en', name: 'English' },
  { code: 'es', name: 'Espanol' },
  { code: 'fr', name: 'Francais' },
]
```

Import that constant into your component.

```
// language-selector.component.ts
import { SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES } from './path/to/supported-languages';

class LanguageSelectorComponent {
  languages = SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES
  
  // ... rest of the methods
}
```

Iterate over the supported languages and display their names.

```html
<!-- my.component.html -->
<select class="form-control" (change)="translateLanguageTo($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.code" [selected]="language.code === translate.currentLang">
        {{ language.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

And define the languages for `ngx-translate` in your `app.component.ts` as follows:

```
import { SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES } from './path/to/supported-languages';

...
this.translate.addLangs(SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.map(l => l.code);
```

By using this strategy you can define all supported languages in one file and easily add/remove languages later without touching other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer as it was useful inspiration, however I decided to go down a slightly different route. I'll outline here for anyone in the future...

Create an enum...

```
export enum SupportedLanguages {
    'en' = 'English',
    'es' = 'Español',
    'fr' = 'Français'
}

export type SupportedLanguage = keyof typeof SupportedLanguages;
```

language selector template...

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="languageKey 
(ngModelChange)="onLanguageChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let language of supportedLanguages | keyvalue" 
        [ngValue]="language.key"
        [selected]="language.key === translate.currentLang">
                {{ language.value }} - {{ language.key }}
    </option>
</select>
```

language selector ts...

```
import { SupportedLanguages } from 'models';

public supportedLanguages = Object(SupportedLanguages);

languageKey: string = this.translate.currentLang;
```